# Linkage of static variables in member functions defined in-class

Tags: c++, dllimport, static-variables, dllexport, linkage

```
//lib.h
#pragma once
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#ifdef BUILD_LIB
#define LIB_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else 
#define LIB_API __declspec(dllimport) /* here */
#endif
#else
#define LIB_API
#endif

void LIB_API boo();

class LIB_API foo {
public:
    int bar() {
        static int a = 0;
        return a++;
    }
};

//lib.cpp
#include "lib.h"

void boo() {
    foo f;
    f.bar();
}

// main.cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include "lib.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    foo f;
    boo();
    printf("%d\n", f.bar());
    return 0;
}
```

For MSVC, without __declspec(dllimport) it appears the variable has multiple instances - the output is 0. Otherwise the output is 1.

When foo::bar is defined in lib.cpp, even without __declspec(dllimport), the output is 1.

I'm not familiar with how other compilers handle exporting and importing symbols, but by default with:

```
g++ -shared lib.cpp -o lib.so
g++ main.cpp -L . lib.so
./a.out
```

The output is 1.

Is it possible that with certain options, g++ will behave like MSVC, that is, producing multiple instances of a?

Does the standard say anything about how functions defined in-class shall be instantiated, and does it have anything to do with how compilers handle static variables declared inside?

---

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Static_local_variables) says:

> Function-local static objects in all definitions of the same inline
> function (which may be implicitly inline) all refer to the same object
> defined in one translation unit.

I guess it's not otherwise guaranteed whatsoever.

Comment: without the `dllimport` how would the compiler know to look to the DLL for the linkage of `a`? That's the entire point is to say that it's an external public symbol. The fact you're defining it in the header complicates things actually because different implementations have different library memory models (MSVC does per DLL/EXE heaps for example for legacy reasons). Realistically this is at best implementation defined behavior.

Comment: @Mgetz g++ seems to export and import all symbols by default, which looks more sane to me, even if it likely costs more link time.

Comment: Except that's insane, it prohibits tons of optimizations and is considered a major anti-pattern to the point gcc introduced a [flag to prevent it.](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility) Ideally you only want your API visible otherwise you have to support a never changing ABI which is nearly impossible. When you export by default you de-facto prohibit inlining by the compiler because the compiler *must* have a symbol to link to etc. That destroys performance as well.

Comment: GCC even has a term for this exact case [vague linkage](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vague-Linkage.html)

Comment: @Mgetz I see now, but I guess GCCs default behaviour is fool-friendly. There must be many like me who expect their program to behave consistently.